# hyperlink in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, html

This is something probably trivial but i can't quite find my way round it:

How do i add a hyperlink from one ruby-file.html.erb to another please?

Comment: This may be useful for you when you get a chance to read it.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

Comment: **You should seriously consider reading the link in Jim's comment.** You've been asking a lot of very basic Rails questions lately. They're the kind of questions that would not be asked by someone who has read the guides. In fact 2 of the answers you accepted link to those guides. The SO community is happy to answer questions, but we're not going to do you much good in the long run if you do not comprehend the basic concepts of the framework.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have been trying to go round A LOT of guides but some things are still not that easy to understand or at least sometimes i won't know exactly where i need to go to find them. I'm basically taking a 'crash' course in the subject as i need it for a tight university deadline so i can assure you I am trying to find a solution before i get here but sometimes its not so obvious to someone who is really new to the language. I really really appreciate the link to the guide and help however

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby uses something called routes. You can create named routes for some operations or you can use resource routes (autogenerated CRUD per resource).

For example if you have route for a model called Car, then calling

```
link_to "Edit my car", edit_car_path(@car)
```

in your view will generate a link.

remember that your are linking to a controller *action* in model/view/controller and not to *pages*